# What are the chances of a random poker hand of having at least one ace?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This problem is found in Richard A. Brauldi's book on Introductory Combinatorics. Now, the problem is to find the probability of a randomly picked poker hand (combination of 5 cards) to have at least one ace. I wanted to check two methods in accomplishing this task: first, through the straight forward subtraction principle; that is, since the total number of poker hands (the sample space) is $^{52}C_5$, and the number of poker hands that *do not* have an ace in them is $^{48}C_5$. Subtracting the former set from the complement we get $886,656$, and this result divided by the size of the sample space gives us our required calculation.

However, when I try calculating with the addition principle, the size of the event does not compare identically with the previous result. This is how I've been calculating: I partitioned the set of all those poker hands that have at least one ace into 4 sets, namely, the poker hands with exactly one ace; those with exactly 2; those with exactly 3; and those with exactly 4. Now, each set can be counted by counting the number of ways an ace can be chosen from the four aces, and by counting the number of ways the rest of the cards may be chosen from the remaining deck. The first set is hence of size $4×^{51}C_4$, the second of size $3!×^{50}C_3$, the third of $4×^{49}C_2$, and the fifth of $1×^{47}C_1$. Funnily, however, these results add up to a sum of $1,121,951$. If the reader could point out the flaw in my reasoning, I, the writer, would be more than obliged. Thank you in advance.

Comment: there are always $48$ non-aces to choose from

Comment: Your remaining deck should *not* include the other aces.

Answer (score 2):

If you use overlapping sets, you need to apply inclusion-exclusion as below, or else add up disjoint cases

(Hands with one ace and any $4$ from remaining $51$)
$\,$- (Hands with two aces and any $3$ from remaining $50$)
$\,$+ (Hands with three aces and any $2$ from remaining $49$)
$\,$- (Hands with four aces and any $1$ from remaining $48$)

$$=\binom41\binom{51}4 - \binom42\binom{50}3 + \binom43\binom{49}3 - \binom44\binom{48}1 = 886 656$$

Comment: @TonyK: You have missed the fact that I applied inclusion-exclusion, rather than addition of disjoint sets. Both give the right figure

Comment: @TonyK This is a correct application of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Compare the value true blue anil obtained with my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry! (But still, inclusion-exclusion is overkill here.)

Comment: @TonyK: As OP was counting wrongly with overlapping sets, I thought I'd show him the correct way to do so.  No sweat ! $\;\;$ :)

Answer (score 1):

Your complementary counting approach is correct.  Since there are $\binom{52}{5}$ hands and $\binom{48}{5}$ hands that do not contain an ace, there are
$$\binom{52}{5} - \binom{48}{5}$$
hands with at least one ace.

We can also count directly.  Since there are $4$ aces and $52 - 4 = 48$ non-aces in a standard deck of cards, the number of ways of selecting exactly $k$ aces and $5 - k$ non-aces is
$$\binom{4}{k}\binom{48}{5 - k}$$
Hence, the number of ways of selecting at least one ace is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{2} + \binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{1}$$

Your answer was too large since you selected from sets that were not disjoint. Therefore, if you selected one of the four aces and four of the other fifty-one cards, your selections include draws with up to four aces rather than a single ace.  Also, you seem to be mixing ordered and unordered selections, which is another source of error.

Comment: Oh my, thank you! What a terribly laughable mistake, really!